# How do I place the registration form in the front page?

Tags: blocks

I am using Drupal 7.

I clicked on Structure > Block > Add Block; I filled in the block title and block description. In the block body, I put in this code.

```
<?php
  $_GET['q'] = 'user/register';
  print drupal_get_form('user_register');
?>
```

I set the text format to PHP (PHP wasn't in the drop down options of text formatting so I added PHP to it), and I clicked on save block.

The block is now created but it's just empty. I can't see any sign up form.

Can someone please put me through? I'm new to Drupal.

I just discovered that I had to activate PHP Filter in core modules (administration > modules). So when I activated PHP Filter module, the registration block I created now shows the word "Array", and also some error in the log.

> Notice: Undefined index: user_register in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 764 of C:\xampp\apps\drupal\htdocs\includes\form.inc).
>   Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'user_register' not found or invalid function name in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 799 of C:\xampp\apps\drupal\htdocs\includes\form.inc).
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion in eval() (line 3 of C:\xampp\apps\drupal\htdocs\modules\php\php.module(80) : eval()'d code).

However, the "create new account and login" menu is now showing; it is only not showing in the block I created for it. What is showing in the block is "Array"; when I click on either "register" or "log in," it takes me away from the front page (to the register page).

Comment: The code you used in the block did not go through. Try posting it again so others can have a look. Also, this part: "so i went to the setting to input it" isn't quite clear - did you enable the core PHP module?

Comment: thanks a lot. i just enabled the core PHP module and it now shows the log in menu. except that it is not showing in the block i created for it. (what is showing in the block is "Array" and when i click on either "register" or "log in" it takes me away from the homepage (to the register page)

Comment: The `drupal_get_form` returns Drupal renderable array as far as I remember, and this is why you see the word 'array'. Try to wrap the drupal_get_form with the render function.

Answer (score 2):

The user register form id is `user_register_form`. Please try it like:

```
$form = drupal_get_form('user_register_form');
print render($form);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Form Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/formblock) module which provides user registration and node creation forms in blocks.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code.

```
print(drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_register_form')));
```

Comment: `drupal_render()` expects a variable passed by reference; you cannot use the value returned from a function, if that function doesn't return a reference.