# Render form node add in page

Tags: nodes, forms

I have these code that render form right:

```
<?php
// we have to access the content of the global-scope variable $user
global $user;
//Checking if the user is registered
if(($user->uid == 0) && (arg(0) != 'user')){
drupal_goto('user/register');
}else{
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
$form = node_add('MY_CONTENT'); return drupal_render($form);}
?>
```

but when upload some images in form widget return some errors:

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'node_form' not found or invalid function name in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 806 of /Users/umbilu/Sites/bedmyboat/includes/form.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: #node in comment_form_node_form_alter() (line 1206 of /Users/umbilu/Sites/bedmyboat/modules/comment/comment.module).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in comment_form_node_form_alter() (line 1223 of /Users/umbilu/Sites/bedmyboat/modules/comment/comment.module).
Notice: Undefined index: #node in i18n_node_form_node_form_alter() (line 434 of /Users/umbilu/Sites/bedmyboat/sites/all/modules/i18n/i18n_node/i18n_node.module).
Notice: Undefined index: actions in i18n_node_form_node_form_alter() (line 448 of /Users/umbilu/Sites/bedmyboat/sites/all/modules/i18n/i18n_node/i18n_node.module).
Warning: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in i18n_node_form_node_form_alter() (line 448 of /Users/umbilu/Sites/bedmyboat/sites/all/modules/i18n/i18n_node/i18n_node.module).
Notice: Undefined index: #node in maxlength_form_alter() (line 188 of /Users/umbilu/Sites/bedmyboat/sites/all/modules/maxlength/maxlength.module).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in maxlength_form_alter() (line 188 of /Users/umbilu/Sites/bedmyboat/sites/all/modules/maxlength/maxlength.module).
Notice: Undefined index: #node in menu_form_node_form_alter() (line 629 of /Users/umbilu/Sites/bedmyboat/modules/menu/menu.module).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in menu_form_node_form_alter() (line 629 of /Users/umbilu/Sites/bedmyboat/modules/menu/menu.module).
Notice: Undefined index: #node in menu_form_node_form_alter() (line 630 of /Users/umbilu/Sites/bedmyboat/modules/menu/menu.module).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in menu_form_node_form_alter() (line 630 of /Users/umbilu/Sites/bedmyboat/modules/menu/menu.module).
Notice: Undefined index: #node in translation_form_node_form_alter() (line 135 of /Users/umbilu/Sites/bedmyboat/modules/translation/translation.module).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in translation_form_node_form_alter() (line 135 of /Users/umbilu/Sites/bedmyboat/modules/translation/translation.module).
Notice: Undefined index: #node in i18n_menu_form_node_form_alter() (line 786 of /Users/umbilu/Sites/bedmyboat/sites/all/modules/i18n/i18n_menu/i18n_menu.module).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in i18n_menu_form_node_form_alter() (line 787 of /Users/umbilu/Sites/bedmyboat/sites/all/modules/i18n/i18n_menu/i18n_menu.module).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in i18n_menu_form_node_form_alter() (line 792 of /Users/umbilu/Sites/bedmyboat/sites/all/modules/i18n/i18n_menu/i18n_menu.module).
Notice: Undefined index: #node in _i18n_node_form_node_form_alter() (line 501 of /Users/umbilu/Sites/bedmyboat/sites/all/modules/i18n/i18n_node/i18n_node.module).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in _i18n_node_form_node_form_alter() (line 520 of /Users/umbilu/Sites/bedmyboat/sites/all/modules/i18n/i18n_node/i18n_node.module).
Notice: Undefined index: field_boat_images in file_ajax_upload() (line 271 of /Users/umbilu/Sites/bedmyboat/modules/file/file.module).
Notice: Undefined index: #suffix in file_ajax_upload() (line 280 of /Users/umbilu/Sites/bedmyboat/modules/file/file.module).
```

I have tried with these:

```
<?php 
if (!function_exists('node_add')) {
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
}
print drupal_render(node_add('on_board'));
?>
```

return these error:

> Strict warning: Only variables should be passed by reference in eval() (line 5 of /Users/umbilu/Sites/bedmyboat/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I place the registration form in the front page?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/93769/how-do-i-place-the-registration-form-in-the-front-page)

Comment: Read what the error message is telling you to fix your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is probably due to the fact, that `node_add` is registered as a menu callback in the node module, and in this menu item definition the include `node.pages.inc` is defined. When you use your own code (like you do) then this automatic inclusion of `node.pages.inc` is not done, so that the necessary API functions are missing, resulting in the error messages that you see.

Therefor, as a general remark, it is usually advisable to create custom modules (or adding functions to template.php, though no buisness logic should be processed there) and implement hooks like `hook_preprocess_page` or even define custom blocks in order to place functional elements in a page.

Anyway, for a solution to your problem, have a look at this question: [Embed a "node add" form in a page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3364/how-can-i-embed-a-node-add-form-in-a-page)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have read How can I embed a "node add" form in a page, but it is little complex for me. Can you explain in very convenient way how to use that code?

Comment: You should try to replace your original code with the first code snippet from the answer of Елин Й. Then you should create a [custom module](https://drupal.org/developing/modules/7) and add the function `function YOURMODULE_menu_alter(&$items)` where YOURMODULE must be replaced with the name of your module. Ideally you would also put the first code snippet in this same module file inside a `hook_preprocess_page()`. See [Understanding the hook system for Drupal modules](https://drupal.org/node/292) for more details about how to use hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Form Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/formblock) module which provides user registration and node creation forms in blocks.